# Cannot set/change default icon for a Chrome webapp (created using Apps Script) in Chrome desktop launcher

Tags: google-chrome-extension, icons, google-chrome-app

I wrote a simple Google Apps script and published it in the Chrome Web Store as an app (I guess "hosted" app. You can find the link here: http://bit.ly/1JTiKLC). I followed the instructions mentioned here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/distribute-web-app

I specified all the required items in the checklist, AFAIK, including icons of the required size. The item is listed and I can download it. However, when it is added in the Chrome desktop launcher, it has the default "apps script" blue icon:

[image: launcher-screenshot]

I want to change this but can't find any way to do so. The link above specifies that there is a way to do this for a new tab page (sec. Updating a web app's icon on the New Tab Page). First of all, I cannot see any link that says "specify an alternative image" anywhere as they say. Could someone elaborate on this. Secondly, is there a similar way to change the launcher icon for apps script webapps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it. Here's the info for someone else who may have the same question: The link appears in the window just after you click "Publish>Register in Chrome Web Store..." in the apps script editor itself. It's not there in the developer dashboard. You can host the image publicly on any site which provides direct links, like imgur. 
[image: edit webapp icon]

This will change the icon in the Chrome new page tab (or in "chrome://apps/") as well as the desktop launcher. Cheers :)